# How do I solve this keyerror when attempting to visualize a networkx graph using pyvis?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx, pyvis

Hello I have another netowrkx question in python.
I am attempting to use the following function to create a visualization but getting keyerror whenever I try to run the code below:

```
G = nx.Graph()
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(
    df_edges,'user_id_x','user_id_y')

node_attr = df_nodes.set_index('user_id')
nx.set_node_attributes(G, node_attr)

communities = community.greedy_modularity_communities(G)

modularity_dict = {} # Create a blank dictionary
for i,c in enumerate(communities): # Loop through the list of communities, keeping track of the number for the community
    for name in c: # Loop through each person in a community
        modularity_dict[name] = i # Create an entry in the dictionary for the person, where the value is which group they belong to.

# Now you can add modularity information like we did the other metrics
nx.set_node_attributes(G, modularity_dict, 'modularity')

def visualize(identity_id,html_name):
    #create subgraph using the provided identity_id
    classx = [n for n in G.nodes() if G.nodes[n]['modularity'] == 
              G.nodes[identity_id]['modularity']]
    SG = G.subgraph(classx)
    
    #instantiate the Network object
    N = Network(height='800px', width='100%', bgcolor='#ffffff', 
                font_color='black',notebook = True, directed=False)
    
    #this line effects the physics of the html File
    N.barnes_hut(spring_strength=0.006)
    
    
    for n in SG:
        if ((SG.nodes[n]['category']=='cust') and (SG.nodes[n]['status']=='ACTIVE')):  # assign color to nodes based on cust status
            color = 'green'
            shape = 'square'
        if ((SG.nodes[n]['category']=='cust') and (SG.nodes[n]['status']=='CLOSED')):  # assign color to nodes based on cust status
            color = 'red'
            shape = 'square'   
        elif SG.nodes[n]['category']=='app':# assign shape to nodes based on cust versus app
            color = 'blue'
            shape = 'triangle'
        N.add_node(n, label=n, color=color,shape = shape)
    
    for e in SG.edges:
        if e in SG.edges:  # add the edges to the graph
            color = 'black'
            width = 2
        N.add_edge(e[0],e[1],color=color, width=width)
   
    N.show_buttons(filter_=True)

    N.show(f'subgraph_{html_name}.html')  # save a html file in current dir
    
    print(f"Number of nodes in this customer's device based network: {SG.number_of_nodes()}")
    
    print('\nList of associated customers and applications based on device:\n')
    display(df_nodes[(df_nodes['user_id'].isin(list(SG.nodes)))])#print list of customer_ids that are associated with the customer
    network_df= df_nodes[(df_nodes['user_id'].isin(list(SG.nodes)))]

visualize('b572f4d3-2c69-48fa-91fe-849fa55d1be7','customerA')
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-124-d0c830d4c4a1> in <module>
----> 1 visualize('b572f4d3-2c69-48fa-91fe-849fa55d1be7','customerA')

<ipython-input-123-5d1d5e9d24a4> in visualize(identity_id, html_name)
     14 
     15     for n in SG:
---> 16         if ((SG.nodes[n]['category']=='cust') and (SG.nodes[n]['status']=='ACTIVE')):  # assign color to nodes based on cust status
     17             color = 'green'
     18             shape = 'square'

KeyError: 'category'
```

This has been very frustrating as this block of code worked perfectly last week, And I am positive I did not change anything critical.

And for those of you that are curious this is what the df_nodes DataFrame looks like:

[image]

It is particularly strange because when I print out the node attribute outside of the function it returns the expected result.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: why dont you print `SG.nodes[n]` as the first line in the loop and see the actual data?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So I think the problem lies in the the modularity function. when i print the nodes outside of the functions Its appears my modularity function is creating an additional node instead of adding to existing nodes. And this new node only contains the attribute : `{'modularity': 1}` verse the expected:
`{'category': 'cust', 'status': 'ACTIVE', 'customer_id': '32f8bd11-83f8-41bd-894f-8786680e5bb9'}`

Comment: I solved the problem. When creating the nodes frame I merged with another table that did not contain attributes for every node in the network. Thus many of the nodes in the subgraphs appear as empty dictionaries and the